# perl regexp problem 2

Tags: regex, perl

I have a list of command to parse...

like:

```
> ls -lart 
> ls 
> ls /etc/passwd 
> ping 
> ping 127.0.0.1
> PING
> LS
```

I have to count the number of times ls and ping was executed, I have to not count uppercase variant like LS and PING, but I have to count command launch with option like "ls -lart"

How to check if a line contain the exact word ls or ping or whatever?

With regular expression!!!

Thanks,

Comment: Have you perhaps thought of doing your _own_ homework?

Comment: I have to agree with paxdiablo, this really isn't tough Perl here. Read `perldoc perlintro` and `perldoc perlretut` and if you still have problems, then ask.

Comment: Thanks! this is not homework, since I'm a little bit old to get homework. I'm studying perl during my spare time after work, and sometimes I'm stuck on stupid problem cause I'm missing some key word or some process. I found this way of learning through question and explanation more effective than reading a whole script. So if you don't want to help me I invite you to not write answer or comment on my question.

Comment: Seriously, you'll learn a lot faster if you try first and post what you've done for a critique.

Comment: @Kerby82, I think it was your question's name "... Problem 2" that made it feel like a homework question. This site does have a bit of an implied "policy" that asks users to try to do it first and then ask about problems, not how do I do x, just to try to avoid doing people's (paying) jobs or homework for them. Seriously though, I learned Perl on my own and I found the Perl documentation (especially `perldoc perlintro`) invaluable. Then, when you have issues pleases post your code and we will all give it a go. No hard feelings!

Comment: @Joel ok! in the previous post I published my code! and if you see my comment below I also found the solution for this problem! I was getting crazy about exact word matching in perl! that's it! No hard feelings at all! thanks to all instead, you are teaching me a very smart way of working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $count = 0;

while (<STDIN>) {
  m/^\s*(ls|ping).*$/;
  $count++ if $1;
}
```

Comment: Hi I found this:  m/^\b(ls|ping)\b/ is the boundary variable

Comment: You are right, using `\b` to delimit the command is more appropriate in this case.